# Adding items to a list until keypress

Tags: python

I have got it to work, except the list doesn't save the inputs properly; it just lists them as three periods. This is the code:

```
names = []
i=0
while 1:
    i+=1
    name=input("Please enter the name")
    if name==" ":
        break
        names.append(names)
        print(names)
```

Comment: You're inputting the "name" into `name` but you are "appending" `names` instead, that's a typo.... change it to `names.append(name)`

Comment: Firstly, It should be names.append(name)

Comment: Also, change `if name==" ":*`if name==" ": to if name==" ": and remove multiple break break as well.

Comment: This code really needs to be made more legible. You do not need to use backticks if you are indenting the code. You do need to indent properly for it to be valid Python code though.

Comment: Also, it is only for Python3 and not Python2. Please remember to mention it next time.

Comment: names = []
count = 0
while True:
    name=input("Please enter the name")
    if name == " ":
        break
    else:
        names.append(name)
    print(names)
    count += 1

Comment: Make sure that your code is formatted properly. It's hard to deduce what you're actual problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Change `names.append(names)` to `names.append(name)`, since you want to append `name` to the list `names` (just a typo I guess).

Also `if name == " "` must be changed to `if name == ""`, since if the user presses **enter** without providing any name, the input is an empty string, not a white space.

Correct code here:

```
names = []
i = 0
while True:
    i += 1
    name = input("Please enter the name ")
    if name == "":
        break
    names.append(name)

print(names)
```